# Replacing a number with a word Java

Tags: java

Been digging around the internet just about all day looking for a solution to this problem. I've just started programming about 2 weeks ago nearly and the fact that I don't really know the proper java lingo yet could be the reason I'm not finding what I'm looking for.

Anyway the program is supposed to:

print out all the numbers from 1 to 100 and if during the iteration the program comes across a number that's divisible by 3 it has to replace that number with "Crackle", if it comes across a number that's divisible by 5 it has to replace that number with "Pop" and it comes across a number that's divisible by both then it has to replace that number with "CracklePop

**I can't get it to print CracklePop for numbers that are divisable by both 3 and 5,** but I can get it to print  Crackle & Pop **but not replace the numbers**.

I've tried using:

**Integer.toString(); ,     Integer.valueOf(); ,     Integer.parseInt();**

None of which I can get to work. This is the code so far:

```
int counter = 0;
int max = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){ 
    if (counter % 3 == 0) { 
        System.out.println("Crackle"); 
    }
    else if(counter % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("Pop"); 
    }
    else if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("CracklePop"); 
    }
    System.out.println(counter); 
    counter++;      
}
```

If if you could also suggest a solution that would be the most robust way of writing a program like this that would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `counter` variable. You can just use the `i` counter itself.

Also you should place the check for both being divisible by 3 and 5 first:

```
int max = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){ 
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("CracklePop"); 
    } else  if (i % 3 == 0) { 
        System.out.println("Crackle"); 
    } else if(i % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("Pop"); 
    } else {
        System.out.println(i); 
    }
}
```

The last `else` will make sure you replace the number with the corresponding string if it matches one of the conditions of being divisible by 3 and/or 5.

Comment: Hi manouti, this worked great thanks :D. Been trying to solve this all day lol. I noticed that when I swapped the counter variable with i it produced the same results but I was convinced I needed it in there for some reason. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

for `counter` = `15`  your last 2 `else if` will never get invoked, you need to re order your if else like

```
if (counter % 5 == 0 && counter % 3 == 0){ 
    System.out.println("CracklePop"); 
} else if (counter % 3 == 0) { 
    System.out.println("Crackle"); 
} else if(counter % 5 == 0){ 
    System.out.println("Pop"); 
} else{
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

still you can store result of `%` in a boolean variable to avoid multiple time calculation in worst case

Comment: I think that he also wants the number to not be displayed at all if anything is displayed on the screen (ergo, if it outputs "Pop", don't display a number). If so, he needs another else statement at the end.

Comment: in that case OP can put printing number in last `else {}`

Comment: I understand that, but OP might not.

Comment: Yeah was wanting the words to replace the numbers like Joe said. I can see your code does that now :D. Thanks for the help this has been doing my head in all day lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your last else/if statement at the beginning. The problem is, when one of your if statements is valid, it will execute that statement and end the if statement. Your last statement will never be executed. Your statement should be:

```
public class CodeCracklePop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int counter = 0;
int max = 100;

for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){
    if (counter % 3 == 0 && counter % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("CracklePop"); 
    } 
    else if (counter % 3 == 0) { 
        System.out.println("Crackle"); 
    }
    else if(counter % 5 == 0){ 
        System.out.println("Pop"); 
    }

    System.out.println(counter); 
    counter++;      
 }       

}

}
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, I didn't know that about if statements I thought the program would just run through the if statements every time it went around the loop. Thanks for pointing that out :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason the numbers aren't replaced is because the Crackle and Pop are printed, but the numbers are also printed afterwards. CracklePop never is printed because anything that would fulfill it would just print Crackle instead. You need to reorder your logic in order for it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
System.out.println(counter);
```

With

```
else {
System.out.println(counter); 
}
```

In addition, as Jigar pointed out above you should test for 3 and 5 first

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int max = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("Crackle");
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("Pop");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Solorad this solution worked great as well thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class CodeCracklePop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       /* int counter = 0; omit this*/
        int max = 100;
    boolean flag = false;

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++){ 

    if(i % 3 == 0){

        System.out.print("Crackle");
        flag = true;

    }

    if(i%5==0){

           System.out.print("Pop");
           flag = true;

    }
    if(!flag)
       System.out.print(""+i);

    flag = false;

    System.out.println("");
        }       

    }

    }
```

A fun way of getting the job done.